# Merging codenames with versions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should we merge all codename tags with the version tags? Already there are tags like lucid and 10.04 which are identical.

Comment: not to mention lucid-lynx and other variants

Comment: Ya. My personal opinion is to use the version numbers exclusively and fix all the 'codename' tags.

Comment: Agreed. Codenames are development versions. Releases are designated by Version numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I hope that over time the [Tag Synonyms](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=discussion&sort=info&pagesize=15) feature on the Info pages will take care of this for us and you'll be able to tag/search with `lucid`, `10.04` and/or `lucid-lynx` and these will be treated as equivalent.

It's early days for that feature, so I see where you're coming from.

Comment: Agreed. we should only merge codenames for consistency i.e lucid and lucid-lynx and keep codenames and version numbers. different people search for different tags.

Answer (score 2):

On the parent site there are (at this moment) 37 questions [tagged with 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.04) and 9 questions [tagged with lucid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lucid). Of the 37 questions tagged with 10.04, 5 are also tagged lucid and 1 is also tagged lucid-lynx.

It looks like thus far 10.04 is the popular choice and I see also the top voted answer to [this related question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/44/should-we-have-a-consistent-naming-scheme).

I think it would make sense for the other two to be suggested as [synonyms for 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=10.04&sort=info&pagesize=15). However, that decision is in the hands of the +1000 users (currently 7) or the moderators (I think).

Answer (score 0):

I think so, although for readability I think that we should give preference to the codename (excluding the animal). For example:

- lucid <= 10.04
- lucid <= lucid-lynx

Etc.

Comment: The result of http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/44/should-we-have-a-consistent-naming-scheme seems to suggest doing it the other way around.

Comment: The code names are confusing. It's hard to tell if they refer to the current release or not.