# Should we have a consistent naming scheme?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is very much related to [this question about merging tags](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/42/merging-codenames-with-versions).

This goes one step further to assume that we SHOULD.

What should the naming convention be?

Answer (score 13):

I vote for just the version number.

- <kbd>10.04</kbd>
- <kbd>9.10</kbd>
- <kbd>9.04</kbd>
- etc...

Comment: +1. Codenames get confusing. Considering Ubuntu's "version" numbers actually have real-world meaning (year.month), they're the easiest and least-ambiguous designators.

Comment: +1 If I read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames correctly, numbers are proffered over codenames after release.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this as an answer to allow seperate up/down voting.

my vote is for [number]-[adjective]-[animal].

This is to include all parts of the version that could be identified to avoid confusion.

Comment: I don't see how using just the version number could be ambiguous (10.4 vs 10.4-lucid-lynx).

Comment: +1 for this as people may search for the codename (especially in google, etc)

Comment: The code names are cute, but I have a really hard time telling them apart. I think the ubuntu community would be well served by discouraging their use (after release at least).